# Providing an index.d.ts file for canonical-json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, types

I'm trying to create an `index.d.ts` file for [`canonical-json`](https://github.com/mirkokiefer/canonical-json/blob/master/index.js).  This is what I have:

```
declare module 'canonical-json' {
    export function stringify(s: any): string;
}
```

Also tried:

```
declare namespace JSON {
  export function stringify(s:any):string;
}

export = JSON;
```

And

```
export as namespace JSON;
export const stringify: (o:any) => string;
```

However I get:

> canonical_json_1.stringify is not a function

For all three attempts.

This is the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cryptojs?file=src%2F%40types%2Fcanonical-json%2Findex.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a common js module, where the entire export is an object you could use the specific `export =` syntax:

```
// src\@types\canonical-json\index.d.ts
declare module 'canonical-json' {
    function stringify(s: any): string;
    export = stringify;
}
// index.ts
import stringify = require('canonical-json');
```

You could also enable `"esModuleInterop": true` to access the export as a default import:

```
// src\@types\canonical-json\index.d.ts
declare module 'canonical-json' {
    function stringify(s: any): string;
    export = stringify;
}
// index.ts
import stringify from 'canonical-json';
```

One final option is to make the definition only have a default export, you would still need `"esModuleInterop": true` since the module does not actually have a default export:

```
// src\@types\canonical-json\index.d.ts
declare module 'canonical-json' {
    export default function stringify(s: any): string;
}

// index.ts
import stringify from 'canonical-json';
```

**Note:** I tested all these configurations in node but I expect in will work the same in other environments.

Comment: You're right of course but I don't understand why you would use an ambient external module declaration. That's a terrible idea

Comment: So I changed it to the first option.  I can the `export` on the same line as the `function` otherwise stackblitz drew a red line, and also changed the import to `import stringify from 'canonical-json';` and now it seems like it's working, but Stackblitz draw a red squiggly under `stringify` with this message `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("canonical-json")' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: I tried the 3rd option with `default` and that works.  I no longer get a red squiggly under `stringify`.